# Django-allauth and password strength on sign up

Tags: django, django-allauth

There is a way to django-allauth take care of password strength checking on sign up?

I saw that it is possible to set the size of the password configuring `ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH` in `settings.py`, but I also like to check other usual things like:

- There is at least one uppercase letter
- There is at least one digit
- There is at least one special character

There is a way to do that with django-allauth?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the default adapter (via `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER`), like this:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def clean_password(self, password):
        # Insert your rules here
```

Note that Django has recently added support for custom password validators. This mechanism will be supported in allauth as well, keep an eye on issue https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1233 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! Here is my solution, hope this help!

```
# project/settings.py:
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'user_profile.adapters.MyAccountAdapter'

# project/user_profile/adapter.py:
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def clean_password(self, password):
        if re.match(r'^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$', password):
            return password
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Error message")
```